# Flutter - Set the scale of a widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create an animation that "pops" the widget to the front and returns to it

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class ScoreCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScoreCounter createState() => new _ScoreCounter();
}

class _ScoreCounter extends State<ScoreCounter> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
      vsync: this,
    )..forward();
  }

  @override
  build(BuildContext context){
    return new AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      child: new Container(width: 200.0, height: 200.0, color: Colors.green),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        //What to return that scales the element
      },
    );
  }
}
```

For rotating, I would use a Transform and return a Matrix. But what should I return to accomplish the scaling animation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're going to size your contents manually you could just read `controller.value` in your builder function and use that to set the size of the container.

Alternatively, you could consider a pair of `SizeTransition`s for each axis. The `Align` class may also be useful because you can set a `sizeFactor` in each dimension.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.sort),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new ScoreCounter(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScoreCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScoreCounter createState() => new _ScoreCounter();
}

class _ScoreCounter extends State<ScoreCounter>
  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      vsync: this,
    )
      ..forward();
  }


  @override
  build(BuildContext context){
    return new AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        double size = _controller.value * 200.0;
        return new Container(width: size, height: size, color: Colors.green);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use SizeTransition. But how do I assign a value of Animation<double> to sizeFactor?

Comment: Your controller is an Animation<double>

Comment: If you want something other than a linear animation, you can also make CurvedAnimations with the controller as a parent, or create Tweens and call Tween.animate using the controller as the animation.

Answer (score 24):

Just as a alternative, to set just scale for a specific `Widget`.

```
Transform.scale(
  scale: 1.0,
  child: Container(
    height: 200.0,
    width: 200.0,
    color: Colors.pink,
  ),
),
```

Comment: how could I remove a scroll when scaling a GridView to fill height of its parent?

Answer (score 2):

### Another Approach is to create generalized Scale Transformation.

Simply add this method to your component

```
  Matrix4 scaleXYZTransform({
    double scaleX = 1.00,
    double scaleY = 1.00,
    double scaleZ = 1.00,
  }) {
    return Matrix4.diagonal3Values(scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ);
  }
```

Now you can easily Scale any widget by wrapping it:

```
 Transform(
          transform: scaleXYZTransform(scaleX: .5, scaleY: .5),
          child: Container(
            child: myAwesomeWidget(),
          ));
```

Comment: Transform widget itself has the same scale. It remains as big as the widget we are scaling. Its has to be scaled .. Anyone have idea ?